# Need matches between 2 ranges to be added to a third range with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, module

I need the code to search through a set range one one worksheet (Shell E20:P37) and compare it to a range on another worksheet (Shift Alignment W4:W20), and place any matches into a new range (Shell W16:W20).

I then need it to sort the new range automatically alphabetically.

I would like for it to update the list as new data is entered in the ranges automatically without a button being clicked.

Here is the code I was working on before, it is not working now.

```
Sub STARCalc()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Cell2 As Range
Dim Names As Range
Dim STAR As Range
Dim Hours As Range
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Row2 As Integer
Dim CurSel As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set CurSel = ActiveCell
Range("W16:W20").ClearContents

Set Names = ActiveSheet.Range("E20", "P37")
Set STAR = Worksheets("Shift Alignment").Range("M4", "M20")
Row = 16

For Each Cell In Names
For Each Cell2 In STAR
    If Cell.Value = Empty Then
    ElseIf Cell2.Value = Empty Then
    ElseIf Cell.Value = Cell2.Value Then
    Else ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 20).Value = Cell2.Value
    End If
    Row = Row + 1

    Range("W16:W20").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("W16") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,   DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
       .SetRange Range("W16:W20")
       .Header = xlNo
       .MatchCase = False
       .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
       .SortMethod = xlPinYin
       .Apply
    End With

    CurSel.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I was stuck in the edit, but your code as you shared won't compile,  You have 2 x `For Each` without the closing `Next`. Also, your `If` is not closing...

Comment: I don't know what that means honestly.

Comment: This is the one I had been working on before.

Comment: Sub STARCalc()

Dim Cell As Range
Dim Cell2 As Range
Dim Names As Range
Dim STAR As Range
Dim Hours As Range
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Row2 As Integer
Dim CurSel As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set CurSel = ActiveCell
Range("W16:W20").ClearContents

Set Names = ActiveSheet.Range("E20", "P37")
Set STAR = Worksheets("Shift Alignment").Range("M4", "M20")
Row = 16

Comment: For Each Cell In Names
    For Each Cell2 In STAR
        If Cell.Value = Empty Then
        ElseIf Cell2.Value = Empty Then
        ElseIf Cell.Value = Cell2.Value Then
        Else ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 20).Value = Cell2.Value
        End If
        Row = Row + 1

Comment: Range("W16:W20").Select
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("W16") _
            , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending,   DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Sort
           .SetRange Range("W16:W20")
           .Header = xlNo
           .MatchCase = False
           .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
           .SortMethod = xlPinYin
           .Apply
        End With

        CurSel.Select

End Sub

Comment: @ShaiRado - Re the `If` statement not closing - As you have edited it, the `If` **is** closed. The IDE will insert the required `:` into `Else ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 20).Value = Cell2.Value`, thus making the `If` block valid.  (Or do I need to go back to bed and get some more sleep before looking at this?)  As the original question had it, i.e. without the space between `Else` and `ActiveSheet`, it wouldn't have worked but, judging by the OP's code in comments, that was probably just a typo created while entering the code into the question and your edit correctly fixed the question typo.

Comment: @YowE3k and ShaiRado. Should the re-edited code Shai updated work then?

Comment: The error I'm getting when I run the code is: "Compile error: For without Next"

Comment: See Shai's first comment - you have 2 x `For Each` without the closing `Next`.  The compiler needs to be **told** which part of your code is meant to be processed `For Each Cell2` (and which part is meant to be processed `For Each Cell`) - it can't **guess**, so you need to include a `Next Cell2` (and `Next Cell`) at the appropriate point in your code where you want it to finish processing one value of `Cell2` (and `Cell`) and start processing the `Next` one.  (Note: `Next Cell2` (and `Next Cell`) can be abbreviated to just `Next` - the `Cell2` (and `Cell`) part of the statement is optional.)

Comment: Once you add the `Next`s and it compiles, it might be worth checking that column 20 ("T") is really where you want your matches to go in `ActiveSheet.Cells(Row, 20).Value = Cell2.Value`. I have an inkling you may actually want them placed in column 23 ("W")